# react-data-tables Undefined Toolbar

Tags: reactjs

Trying to use react-data-tables here and getting errors left right and center. Going crazy.

After following the instructions as per https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid and using the code samples from http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/filterable-sortable-grid I am having the following issues.

If I use this in my file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid';
import ReactDataGridPlugins from 'react-data-grid/addons';

var Toolbar = ReactDataGridPlugins.Toolbar;
var Selectors = ReactDataGridPlugins.Data.Selectors;
```

I get a "Cannot read property 'Toolbar' of undefined.

If I try

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid';
import Toolbar from 'react-data-grid/addons';
import Selectors from 'react-data-grid/addons';
```

I get the following error:

React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `HostProviderList`.

And if I try

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid';
import {Toolbar} from 'react-data-grid/addons';
import {Selectors} from 'react-data-grid/addons';
```

I get this error

Warning: Unknown props `onGridSort`, `columns`, `rowGetter`, `rowsCount`, `minHeight`, `onRowUpdated`, `toolbar`, `onAddFilter`, `minColumnWidth`, `columnEquality`, `enableCellSelect`, `rowHeight`, `enableRowSelect`, `rowKey`, `rowScrollTimeout`, `cellNavigationMode`, `headerRows`, `columnMetrics`, `cellMetaData`, `selectedRows`, `rowSelection`, `expandedRows`, `rowOffsetHeight`, `sortColumn`, `sortDirection`, `onSort`, `totalWidth`, `onViewportKeydown`, `onViewportKeyup`, `onViewportDragStart`, `onViewportDragEnd`, `onViewportDoubleClick`, `onColumnResize` on  tag. Remove these props from the element.

I am not sure what to do here. If I do just the basic data-grid as per the online example it works fine. However as soon as I try anything with the addons.jsx file it fails.

On a side note
    nmp install react-data-grid/addons

does not work. The git repo is not found. However I do see that after doing an npm install of react-data-grid I do have a addons.jsx file that imports dist/react-data-grid.ui-plugins.js

Comment: npm install react-data-grid/addons is not required. import { Toolbar, Selectors } is the right way. Unknown props may be because of issues with not defining propTypes.

Comment: In the new codebase, I did not find {Selectors} in the addons - https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/master/src/addons/index.js. You will have to import {Toolbar, Data} from 'react-data-grid/addons'. Followed by const Selectors = Data.Selectors.

Comment: That worked mostly. Now I get an error saying TypeError: Cannot read property '__metaData' of undefined. Any ideas @Vijay

Answer (score 3):

The right way to import is

```
import { Toolbar, Data } from 'react-data-grid/addons';
const Selectors = Data.Selectors;
```

Comment: This almost got me all the way. Thanks so much.  Now the table is sortable and the Toolbar shows up to allow the filter row to be added. The only issue that seems to exist is when I try and type something into the filter input I get the following error and the box doesnt accept / show the typed text

    TypeError: Cannot read property '__metaData' of undefined